# Move all files in a folder to other in google drive using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

i'm trying to move all files in a folder to another. The source folder is in the root of my Drive.

It should be something link this, but right now it doesn't enter the for loop:

```
function movefiles() {

var folderName = 'foldername'
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();
var contents = folder.getFiles();
Logger.log(contents.length);

for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
//here the code to move files, for now just this
    file = contents[i];    
    Logger.log(file.getName());
    }
};
```

But the instruction `contents.length` just give me an "undefined" and so it doesn't enter the for loop. What i'm doing wrong?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be like this:

```
function movefiles() {

var folderName = 'foldername'
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();
var files = folder.getFiles();

while (files.hasNext()) {

var file = files.next();
var fileName = file.getName();

  Logger.log(fileName);
  Logger.log(file.getDateCreated());
  Logger.log(file.getSize()); 
 Logger.log(file.getMimeType());
}  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

[`getFiles()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFiles()) does not return an array, so has no `length` property. Instead it returns a [`FileIterator`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator).

An example of how to use this can be seen [here in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app).

E.g.

```
// Log the name of every file in the user's Drive.
var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  Logger.log(file.getName());
}
```

Comment: jeje, i notice, but posted later than you xD